# Factoring RSA if prime p is used as the private exponent

Tags: encryption, rsa, factoring, decryption

I've got two 1024 bits primes $p,q$, and $n = p \cdot q$.
Now I know the result of $ c^{p} \bmod n = x$, also the value of $c$ is given, I wonder if it is possible to factorize $n$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) we know
$$
a^p \equiv a \pmod{p}\,.
$$
Applying this to the present problem, $c^p \equiv c \equiv x \pmod{p}$, and thus with high probability $p = \gcd(x - c, n)$.

Comment: The conclusion "thus $p=\gcd(x-c,n)$" is unwarranted. That's overwhelmingly likely for random $c$. Baring this, sure $p$ divides $x-c$, but it can happen that $x\equiv c\pmod n$, in which case $\gcd(x-c,n)$ is $n$ and does not reveal a factorization of $n$. In that case, it's worth trying if $\gcd(c,n)$ is a non-trivial factor of $n$, but that's not certain either. Small example: take $p=109$, $q=211$. Now $x\equiv c\pmod n$ occurs for $763$ values of $c\in[0,n)$, that is probability $7/q>3.3\%$ for random $c$. Within these only $114$, that is $<15\%$, are such that $\gcd(c,n)$ is $p$ or $q$.

Comment: Point well taken. This happens when $p \bmod \mathrm{ord}_q(x) \in {0,1}$. The other 114 aren't really valid elements of $\mathbb{Z}_n^\ast$, since they are multiples of $p$ or $q$ and amount to guessing one of the factors.